# about backpropagation and sigmoid function

Tags: neural-network

I have been reading this ebook about ANN:https://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf

and got a doubt about the effect of the sigmoid function for calculating the errorB. In the text says that if I have threshold neuron I can use:

Target-Output

but because I have a sigmoid function involved I should add:

Output(1-Output)

and end up with:

ErrorB=OutputB(1-OutputB)(TargetB-OutputB)

I mean why I should add the part of O(1-O), I have tried with different values, but I really do not get the intuition why it should be in that way.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kelu stated, that part of the equation is based on derivatives of your transfer function (in this case sigmoid). To understand why you need derivatives, you need to understand how the [delta rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule) works(*):

[image: Delta rule]

Your overall goal is to minimize the error in the network's output using gradient descent. [Gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) itself tries to find a minimum in the error function (E) by taking steps proportional to the negative of the gradient. A gradient is simply the derivative and the reason you're working with derivatives mathematically is that *gradients point in the direction of the **greatest** rate of increase* of the (error) function. Conclusion: Since you wanna **minimize** the error, you go the **opposite** way of the gradient.

This is the intuitive reason for using gradients. If you want the mathematical derivation, you should check [this basic wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule) (additional comment as it's not mentioned anywhere: the g'(x) in the article is the first derivative of g(x))

Other transfer functions can be used, e.g. linear (in this case there is no g'(x) term as the derivative is simply a constant) or hyperbolic tangent in which case the derivative is something different again.

---

(*) Equation is derived from following equation where you start by minimizing the error of the output:

[image: error function]

Answer (score 1):

It is like that because of the fact that `Output(1-Output)` is a derivative of sigmoid function (simplified). In general, this part is based on derivatives, you can try with different functions (from sigmoid) and then you have to use their derivatives too to get a proper learning rate.

If you want you can take a look at my implementation (it's far from perfect, but maybe you will get some idea from it ;)), it's a simple project I made on my university - https://github.com/kelostrada/neuron-network